# How to get JSON data of console.log inside function and apply it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, promise

I want to get JSON data using fetch method and apply it to react component.
(custom block component for WordPress)

Here is the code I wrote

```
function getCategories() {
    fetch('sample.json')
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((obj) => {
        console.log(obj)
    })
}
```

console.log result

```
[
 {value: 15, label: "Cat1"}
 {value: 21, label: "Cat2"}
 {value: 18, label: "Cat1"}
]
```

I want to apply "console.log" data to the component below

```
<Select
    value={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx ) }
    onChange={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx }
    options={  !!! I want use it HERE !!!  }
    />
```

My idea is to do something like this

```
function getCategories() {
    ...
}

<Select
    value={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx ) }
    onChange={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx }
    options={ getCategories() }
    />
```

If I put return at first, function returns
Promise Object and fails.
I just want just Promise Value.

```
function getCategories() {
    return fetch('sample.json') // ← add return
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then((obj) => obj
    })
}

<Select
    value={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx ) }
    onChange={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx }
    options={ getCategories() }
    />
```

By hard coding it's working fine

```
<Select
    value={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx ) }
    onChange={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx }
    options={ [
        {value: 15, label: "Cat1"}
        {value: 21, label: "Cat2"}
        {value: 18, label: "Cat1"}
    ]  }
    />
```

It's not nesessary to be function if there is better way to get JSON data.
(It's just my idea..)
Hope someone help me.

Comment: is it a dropdown?

Comment: execute the getCategories in didMount and store the array in the state, pass the state to the options. You only need to call the endpoint once

Comment: Yes, it will be dropdown list.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I'm very beginner at programming. 
If you show me the specific code I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should separate the data fetching into component rendering.

```
class Component {
  constructor () {
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    fetch('config')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({data}));
  }

  render () {
    {this.state.data && (
      <Select options={this.state.data} />
    )}
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I have to learn what the "componentDidMount" is, but your code worked fine! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use `state` for your options

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

function getCategories() {
    return fetch('sample.json') // ← add return
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then((obj) => setOptions(obj))
    })
}
```

And then use options inside Select

```
<Select
    value={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx ) }
    onChange={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx }
    options={options}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to fetch the categories in an effect (or componentDidMount if using a class component) and store the result in state. At that point, the data is accessible to your Select component to use whenever it renders.

```
function CategoriesSelect() {
  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('sample.json')
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((obj) => {
        setCategories(obj)
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <Select
      value={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx ) }
      onChange={ xxxxxxxxxxxxx }
      options={categories}
    />
  )
}
```